# ListView behaviour varies on different android versions

Tags: android, listview, versions

I've encountered a strange problem while developing a very simple app for android. I have an `Activity` with `ListView` which is supported by a `Custom ArrayAdapter`. In my `XML layout` file everything is very simple: main `LinearLayout` is holding another `LinearLayout` as a container for `ListView`. Main `LinearLayout` has a background image - png file with resolution 800x1280 without transparent pixels. If my `LinearLayout`-container for `ListView` also has a background image - a png file with the same resolution, but it has transparency - scrolling in 4.x android is fine; in 5.x becomes laggy; in 6.x becomes just impossible to scroll. At the same time if container-`LinearLayout` has no background or there is only one non-transparent background in one of the `LinearLayout` objects, everything is fine.

My question is what is the difference in such a basic thing making it lag so much on newer versions? For me it just does not make any sense, because `ListView` is not marked as deprecated.

The problem is exactly with the `ListView`, because I have another activity with a `HorizontalScrollView`, and it runs well on all versions both png files in the `layout`.

Layout code:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:clickable="false"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:measureWithLargestChild="false">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/container_list"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_vert">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/lessonsList"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:scrollbarSize="1px"
        android:layout_margin="12dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/adView">

</LinearLayout>
```

And the sample code:

```
private void FillListView()
{
    ArrayAdapter<Lesson> adapter = new MyListAdapter();
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lessonsList);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Lesson>
{
    MyListAdapter()
    {
        super(MenuActivity.this, R.layout.lesson_item, lessons);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View lessonView = convertView;
        if (lessonView == null) 
        {
            lessonView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.lesson_item, parent, false);
        }
        return lessonView;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** I found out that this problem is connected not only with `ListView`. I have an `Activity` without any scroll views, there are just three not too big images(about 500x500 each one), one big image(1280x800) and four small ones(about 100x100), some of them with text on their `View`s. I can see the same strange behaviour: on 4.x it works fine without any lags, on 5.x it begins to lag and on 6.x it lags even more.

Comment: Add layout code

Comment: This is weird problem. I think, It's really hard to tell why this is happening without looking at complete code

Comment: @indramurari The code is very simple. I commented allmost everything in ArrayAdapter to make sure that this is not my mistake. Its not about code, because I left only the parts without which it would not compile. The items of the ListView have only one ImageView with a standard 64x64 android image of a star. Anyway, I will post the code now.